# Почему при обращении к базе данных могут быть пустые поля в TcxGrid?

Tags: delphi, firebird, devexpress, interbase, delphi-10.3-rio

TcxGrid (DevExpress)

Запрос к базе выполняется, переменные передаются через sql запрос, количество строчек выводится верно (если поменять входной параметр, количество строк будет совпадать с ожидаемым).

```sql
select * from my_procedure(:val)
```

```pascal
    pFIBDataSet1.Close();
    pFIBDataSet1.ParamByName('val').AsString := editTitle.Text;
    pFIBDataSet1.Open;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

В общем, в `TcxGrid` у `Columns` есть свойство `DataBinding`, и её надо поставить на имя выходных параметров от `DataSet'а`.